# position:absolute behaving strangely until I uncheck and recheck css rule

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a sidebar, which has images for recent posts. Over those images should be text, positioned absolutely. It should look like this...
[image]

...instead the text displays like this...

[image]

...however, when I inspect, and uncheck position:absolute, then recheck it, it displays fine.

You can see an example here.. https://evolvefitness.co.uk/blog/the-four-best-idiot-proof-exercises/

Here's a snippet of the html...

```
<ul>
  <li class="grid-100 grid-parent tablet-grid-33">
    <a href="https://evolvefitness.co.uk/blog/five-steps-to-shoulders-that-dont-hurt/" title="Look Five Steps To Shoulders That Don't Hurt">
      <img width="504" height="500" src="https://evolvefitness.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/IMG_5085-e1520514533997-504x500.jpg" class="attachment-sideline size-sideline wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://evolvefitness.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/IMG_5085-e1520514533997-504x500.jpg 504w, https://evolvefitness.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/IMG_5085-e1520514533997-150x150.jpg 150w" sizes="(max-width: 504px) 100vw, 504px">
      <h4>Five Steps To Shoulders That Don't Hurt</h4>
    </a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

...and some css...

```
.pecent ul li a {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
min-height: 100px;
}

.pecent ul li h4 {
text-transform: uppercase;
background: #e83443;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
z-index: 9;
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
left: 0px;
font-size: 26px;
}
```

Comment: which browser does this issue affect?

Comment: .pecent ul li a - add display: block;

Comment: give it a width or set the right value (ps your selectors are very inefficient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing a `display:block` on `.pecent ul li a`:

```
.pecent ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: block;  /* add this */
}
```